# solarisstudio12.3 installation on Solaris 11 machine

Tags: solaris, sunstudio

I am trying to install solaris studio 12.3 on a Solaris 11 x86 machine.

I have downloaded oracle cert and key from mentioned link, but while publishing am getting following error.

```
pkg set-publisher -k Oracle_Solaris_Studio.key.pem -c Oracle_Solaris_Studio.certificate.pem -g **PORTAL** solarisstudio
pkg set-publisher: The origin URIs for 'solarisstudio' do not appear to point to a valid pkg repository.
Please verify the repository's location and the client's network configuration.
Additional details:

Unable to contact valid package repository
Encountered the following error(s):
Unable to contact any configured publishers.
This is likely a network configuration problem.
1: Framework error: code: 7 reason: Failed connect to pkg.oracle.com:443; Connection refused
URL: '**PORTAL**' (happened 4 times)
2: Framework error: code: 28 reason: Connection timed out after 60000 milliseconds
URL: '**PORTAL**' (happened 4 times)
```

Please let me know if further information is required.

NOTE **PORTAL** - https://pkg.oracle.com/solarisstudio/release

Comment: `Failed connect to pkg.oracle.com:443` — are you behind a firewall or otherwise need to go through a web proxy for access to remote web sites?

Comment: Thanks alanc, yes we were behind a proxy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configuring correct proxy settings as pointed out by alanc, resolved the issue.